# RegExp online builder?

Tags: regex

Is there a such a tool out there? I need to have one for parse something like [!790123] that has square brackets with "!" follow by any integer number.

Comment: Spend 15 minutes reading about how the characters of regex works and then you will be able to do anything. I use RegExr.com to test out my expressions

Comment: `\[!\d+\]` for this specific example, but I agree with @Katamari -- investing a bit of time in learning regexes is well worth it in the long run

Comment: Better ask this sort of questions at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have look at https://regex101.com/r/jA9rH9/1

Answer (score 1):

Not online, but I generally use grep and then sed to build my regexps. If you have one that does coloured output it is very easy to see if it is getting the matches you want on some test data.